# How do I pass an object from javascript to PHP?

Tags: 7, ajax

I set up a hook_menu like this:

```
$items['fleet/construct'] = array(
  'page callback' => 'construct_fleet',
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
);
```

Then I set up a js file with this:

```
$.post({
  url: '/fleet/construct/',
  data: {new_ships: [1,2,3,4], destroyed_ships: [5,6,7,8]},
  success: finalizeFleetResponse
});
```

How do I access the data from inside my menu callback function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a POST, it is the same way you, use

```
$new_ships = $_POST['new_ships'];
$destroyed_ships = $_POST['destroyed_ships'];
```

Read more on php [POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php).

Comment: Not sure why the below didn't work, but this did. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Drupal doesn't provides an API to access POST variables. Probably because what's provided by PHP itself is enough. To retrieve the data, you can use [`filter_input()`](http://be.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php):

```
$new_ships = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'new_ships', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);
$destroyed_ships = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'destroyed_ships', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);
```

Comment: To casual readers: Just note that this appeared in PHP 5.2, so older systems may not have this function. This is a question about Drupal 7, which requires PHP 5.2.5 or higher; if you are using Drupal 6, this answer doesn't work for you.